# Cannot find package '@libs/ddbClient'

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules

I am learning nodejs and I am struggling how to do an import for a different file. Basically, I have my ddbClient.ts file in `libs` folder and I am not able to import it. This is the repo https://github.com/EstefaniaExamples/NursertApp/tree/main/children-api and this is the error description (I cannot see anything wrong)

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-error-err-module-not-found-cannot-find-module

Basically, we need to specify the extension of the file when we use type: module in the package.json